# BigQuery - Scheduled Query Update Notification Email

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-metrics

Is there a way to update the scheduled query notification email to something custom?

By default it is the email of the creator, however, this is often a service account with no true email recipient.

e.g with terraform provisioning, we would have a service account.  We would want to update the email notification target from the SA to a support email so failures would be routed more correctly?

Ive checked the documentation and I could be missing it, but does not seem an option, unless Ive missed something via the CLI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since scheduled Query IDs **always** start with "scheduled_query_[runsID]", search for *scheduled_query*_ using [advanced logs queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries)
2. Create a [logs-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#overview_of_logs-based_metric_types) based on your BigQuery scheduled update log.
3. Create an [alerting policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#alert-on-lbm) using the logs-based metric created in step 1.
4. While creating the alerting policy in step 3, select email as a [notification channel](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels).
5. In notification channel, add your email address to get all the notifications.

Comment: Thanks!  Hope this gets made a little easier in the future, but thanks for the solution

Comment: This advanced query worked well for us. 
`logName="projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME_HERE/logs/bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com%2Ftransfer_config"
severity=ERROR`